# PhoneGap IOS 5.1 - PhoneGap getPicture() always returns the imageUri rather than Base64

Tags: iphone, ios5, cordova

I am trying to capture an image on an IOS5.1 application using PhoneGap. For somereason my success callback function is always given the file Uri rather than the Base64 encoded version. This is my getPicture call:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(captureSuccess, captureError,
                {
                    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                    quality : 40,
                    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG
                });
```

Can someone tell me why this is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug. Shaz has fixed it. 1.6.1 to be out Monday.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-496